# Reference to self type in parameterized trait

Tags: scala

I have the following problem: I would like to have an 'instance' (parameterized trait) and 'configuration', and the latter is parameterized by the instance type:

```
trait Kind
trait Kind1 extends Kind
trait Kind2 extends Kind

trait Instance[T <: Kind] {
  def configuration: InstanceConfiguration[Instance[_]]
}

trait InstanceConfiguration[+T <: Instance[_]] {
}

class AInstance extends Instance[Kind1] {
  override def configuration: AConfiguration = ???
}

class AConfiguration extends InstanceConfiguration[AInstance] {
}

class BInstance extends Instance[Kind1] {
  override def configuration: AConfiguration = ???
}
```

So, the issue is that `InstanceConfiguration[Instance[Kind2]]` cannot be used as a configuration for `Instance[Kind1]`, but now it is too generic, and I'd like compiler to give out error on `BInstance.configuration`.

So how do I change definition of configuration in the Instance trait to reference the concrete InstanceConfiguration of the concrete type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use F-Bounded polymophism. I recommend reading [the section](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded) in Twitter's Scala School, but in brief, `Instance` needs to take the concrete type as a type parameter:

```
trait Kind
trait Kind1 extends Kind
trait Kind2 extends Kind

trait Instance[A <: Instance[A, T], T <: Kind] {
  self: A =>
  def configuration: InstanceConfiguration[A]
}

trait InstanceConfiguration[+T <: Instance[_, _]] {
}

class AInstance extends Instance[AInstance, Kind1] {
  override def configuration: AConfiguration = ???
}

class AConfiguration extends InstanceConfiguration[AInstance] {
}

class BInstance extends Instance[BInstance, Kind1] {
  override def configuration: AConfiguration = ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now i understand that. The only missing part in your solution is self-reference (`self: A =>`) that prevents declarations like `class BInstance extends Instance[AInstance,Kind1]`

Comment: Good idea, the self-type does make it stricter. Your edit was rejected but I went and made the same change.